# MySQL - Group results by weeks in a date range

Tags: mysql, sql, date-range

I have a `users` table that stores TIMESTAMP, when their account was created.  I'm trying to write a query that will show the new users that signed up grouped by week (Starting Mondays), in a given period of time. A director will go in and pick the report date ranges, thus the 2 variables. They should see results that display all new users that have signed up between the 2 selected variable dates, grouped by Week (Monday start of the Week)

**Variables:**
@StartRangeSelectDate
@EndRangeSelectDate

**User Table:**

```
| id         | TIMESTAMP
----------------------------------------------
| 1          | 2013-09-02
| 2          | 2013-09-08
| 3          | 2013-09-12
| 4          | 2013-09-27
```

**Result Should Be (when selected start date is something like 2013-09-01 and end date is 2013-09-29:**

```
| YearWeek         | # of New Users
----------------------------------------------
| 2013 36          | 2
| 2013 37          | 1
| 2013 38          | 0
| 2013 39          | 1
```

**Query to Display Total New Users in Date Range, but just not yet grouped by weeks in the date range:**

```
SELECT COUNT(user.id) AS '# of New Users in Date Range'
FROM user 
WHERE user.Inactive = 0
    AND user.TimeStamp BETWEEN @StartRangeSelectDate AND @EndRangeSelectDate;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT yearweek(`TimeStamp`, 1) yw,
       COUNT(id) AS '# of New Users in Date Range'
FROM user 
WHERE Inactive = 0
AND TimeStamp BETWEEN @StartRangeSelectDate AND @EndRangeSelectDate
GROUP BY yw
```